# Determine the type of characters

Tags: prolog

I would like to determine in Prolog the type of a string of characters, if it is alphabetic, alphanumeric or numeric. 
For example:

```
"I use this page" alphabetic

"0c0d24e" alphanumeric
```

How can i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the predicate available is [char_type](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=char_type/2)/2, or better, code_type/2.
To apply to each code in string, use maplist/2. The only problem it's the wrong arguments order of code_type. Then a service predicate is needed (or download [lambda](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=lambda), if you're using SWI-Prolog, with `?- pack_install(lambda).`).

Without lambda:

```
code_type_(X,Y) :- code_type(Y,X).

?- maplist(code_type_(alpha), "abc").
true.
```

With lambda:

```
?- [library(lambda)].
?- maplist(\C^code_type(C,alpha), "abc").
true.
```

*edit* after comments, it's apparent that more flexible parsing is required. A DCG it's the recommended way to go: library([dcg/basics](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/vnc/prolog/lib/swipl/library/dcg/basics.pl)) offers some prebuilt 'categorizer', and highlights the proper way to write your own, combining with code_type: for instance, here is a recently added rule:

```
%%  prolog_var_name(-Name:atom)// is semidet.
%
%   Matches a Prolog variable name. Primarily  intended to deal with
%   quasi quotations that embed Prolog variables.

prolog_var_name(Name) -->
    [C0], { code_type(C0, prolog_var_start) }, !,
    prolog_id_cont(CL),
    { atom_codes(Name, [C0|CL]) }.

prolog_id_cont([H|T]) -->
    [H], { code_type(H, prolog_identifier_continue) }, !,
    prolog_id_cont(T).
prolog_id_cont([]) --> "".
```

see how code_type/2 is used to qualify single characters...

*more edit* - note: untested

```
qualify_atom(Atom, Type) :-
   atom_codes(Atom, Codes),
   qualify_codes(Codes, Type).

qualify_codes(Codes, Type) :-
   (  maplist(code_type_(alnum), Codes)
   -> Type = alnum
   ;  maplist(code_type_(alpha), Codes)
   -> Type = alpha
   ;  Type = unknown
   ).
```

then, to work on a list

```
?- maplist(qualify_atom, Atoms, Types).
```

*edit*

An update of this answer is mandatory: since library(yall) has been released in SWI-Prolog, and is autoloaded, we can now write:

```
?- maplist([C]>>code_type(C,alpha), `abc`).
```

Also, note the change in literal representation: double quotes in SWI-Prolog ver.7+ don't represent anymore a list of character codes.

Comment: For alphabetic i use `alpha`, for alphanumeric i use `alnum`, but if i have this string "a/b" how can i classify it?

Comment: @JoachimLow the `code_type` predicate recognizes a variety of character types. It would characterize "/" as `ascii`, `graph`, `punct`, etc. An alphabetic character falls into some of these categories, but not all. If you said `maplist(code_type_(ascii), "a/b").` you'd get true. It's up to you how you want to characterize "a/b" or how much detail you need. CapelliC's solution is enough to categorize a string as either alphabetic, alphanumeric, or other. If you need more detailed categorization, can you specify what you want exactly?

Comment: Ok, but if i used `ascii` i recognize all. I need of a type that recognize "a/b" or "a-B" ect, but don't recognize "abc" or "abc2".

Comment: The 'right' way to do is via DCG. You can combine with code_type to get compact and reusable code. But of course we need more detail, as @mbratch pointed out.

Comment: Sorry, i have a list of strings and I want to specify if they are alphabetic, alphanumeric or other, where for other i mean all the rest, for example  "a/b", "-f-d" ect.

Comment: I have a problem, if i have an atom, code_type does not work. I have a list of atoms and if i take one of them, code_type does not work. How can i do?

Comment: I tried using these predicates with GNU Prolog, but it caused an error: `error(existence_error(procedure,code_type/2),letter/3)`. Are `code_type` and `char_type` available in GNU Prolog?

Comment: @AndersonGreen: no, but it's easy to code: for instance `code_type(C,upper) :- between(0'A,0'Z,C).` and so on. Composite classes could reuse simpler one, like in `code_type(C,alnum) :- code_type(C,upper);code_type(C,lower);code_type(C,digit).`

Comment: @CapelliC The implementation of `code_type(C,upper)` is less obvious, though. How can it be implemented in GNU Prolog?

Comment: @AndersonGreen: exactly as I wrote above (I tested it). It works in 'generative' as well as 'check' mode.